# How to make one-to-many association with sequelize-typescript using different foreign key

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I've been trying to make one-to-many relation using different column then primaryKey with sequelize-typescript but it keep targeting primary key of one table which crashes the application.

```
import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  ForeignKey,
  PrimaryKey,
  AutoIncrement,
  Unique,
  CreatedAt,
  UpdatedAt,
  BelongsTo,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import sequelize from "../../db_config";
import Customer from "../customer/customer.model";
import UserDTO from "./dto/user.dto";

@Table({ tableName: "users", initialAutoIncrement: "1000" })
class User extends Model<UserDTO> {
  @Column
  user_id: string;

  @Unique
  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column
  password: string;

  @Column
  user_name: string;

  @Unique
  @Column({ unique: true })
  phone_number: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Customer)
  @Column
  account_number: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Customer, { foreignKey: "account_number" })
  customer: Customer;

  //
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Unique
  @Column
  id: number;

  @Column({ allowNull: false, defaultValue: false })
  status: boolean;

  @CreatedAt
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  updated_at: Date;
}

export default User;
```

```
// Second Table
import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  ForeignKey,
  PrimaryKey,
  AutoIncrement,
  Unique,
  CreatedAt,
  UpdatedAt,
  HasMany,
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import User from "../user/user.model";
import CustomerDTO from "./dto/customer.dto";
//
@Table({ tableName: "customers", initialAutoIncrement: "1000" })
class Customer extends Model<CustomerDTO> {
  @Column
  customer_name: string;

  @Unique
  @Column({ unique: true })
  account_number: string;

  @Column
  city: string;

  @Column
  owner_name: string;

  @HasMany(() => User)
  user: User[];
  //
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Unique
  @Column
  id: number;

  @Column({ allowNull: false, defaultValue: false })
  status: boolean;

  @CreatedAt
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  updated_at: Date;
}
//
//
export default Customer;
```

Keep getting this error
sqlMessage: "Referencing column 'account_number' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'users_ibfk_1' are incompatible."

Comment: Did you try to indicate your custom source field for BelongsTo in `targetKey` option?